# How to limit the record of children's attribute in laravel eloquent

Tags: laravel

I am creating a comment section using laravel with the example entries below:

```
id | comment | parent_id
1     test        1
2     test        1
3     test        1
4     test        2
5     te          2
6     test        1
7     test        2
```

I get these data from an API request. Let's say, I want to get all comments and limit the replies up to 2 records per query. From the given test sample above, the result should be:

```
id | parent_id
 1     1
 2     1
 4     2
 5     2
```

**My question is**, how to get all replies (parent_id > 0) and **limit & offset** the query per request?

My current query is:

```
Comment::where('parent_id', '>' , 0)->get();
```

Comment: r u using mysql driver?

Comment: @TsaiKoga Yes, I am using mysql.

Comment: if the parent comments are small, you can loop parent_ids and query the its children with limit method, and then union them.

Comment: @TsaiKoga I understood what you meant. I can do it using loop. But then, there is a need to get the data using single query

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use pagination to limit the number of the elements:

```
Comment::where('parent_id', '>' , 0)->paginate(15);
```

Replace the "15" with your limit.

Also, you can check Laravel docs about pagination: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/pagination

Comment: This doesn't work properly. Example: 
id - 1, 3, 5 (odd) and parent_id = 1
id - 2, 4, 6 (even) and parent_id = 2

Comment: @smzapp Another helpful method is to chunk your results https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#chunking-results